# Get list of callback functions for success and error in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I get list of all functions that are binding to success and error of ajax call. I need this to conditional call an error generic function if no one is binding to an error callback.

Comment: Would including an extra library be acceptable? There are things that do this really well - the problem is that jQuery's promises are rather bad.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum why promises are bad?

Comment: @Pilot promises are awesome, jQuery promises are bad. Some other promise libraries have this functionality built in (detecting unhandled rejections).